# Angular 2 i18n extract tool Error

Tags: angular, internationalization, webpack

trying to integrate i18n as described in the cookbook guide,
when i run the extract tool to generate the xlf file I get the following error:

> Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 52:19 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol OrchestratorModule in D:/workspace/frontend/my-app/src/app/orchestrator/orchestrator.module.ts

Basically in the line 52 of the module declaration there is a lambda defining a custom provider for HTTP.
I only have this problem with the i18n extract tool.
Anyone faced this before? thanks

**EDIT : code from line 51, in the providers section of the module:**

```
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
                   auth: AuthenticationService) => {
        return new LoyHttp(
            backend, defaultOptions, auth);
      },
      deps: [
        XHRBackend, RequestOptions, AuthenticationService
      ]
    }
```

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: I can show part of it

Comment: just for info, this works just perfect for building serving and testing, I only get this error with the extract tool of i18n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
export function loyHttp(backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
                   auth: AuthenticationService) {

return new LoyHttp(backend, defaultOptions, auth);

}

    { provide: Http, useFactory: loyHttp, 
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, AuthenticationService]
    }
```

I believe this is the solution.